# How can I re-write this SQL purely in Scala (Spark)

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Not experienced in Scala and have tried a few things but at this point, I am a bit stuck.  I am trying re-write this SQL purely in Scala.  Trying to get the most popular name for each year.  Any thoughts?

```
select year, first_name
from (select year, first_name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
     from popularnames
     group by year, first_name
    ) yn
where seqnum = 1;
```

popularnames is my temp table created off of a dataframe in Spark.

Comment: What's is your sql database? Not sure, but the `order by count(*)` seems weird to me (all the elements of your partition would share the same "count", huh?)

Comment: I will add more detail.  I am running this in Spark.

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? Encountered error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.